# How to preview changes made dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a website where a user can change particular parts of their site. But before they can submit changes, I want them to be able to preview them. I have thought about taking the innnerHTML of the whole page and then editing that function. Maybe there is a way in which I can still search for & make dynamic changes to the variable in which I have assigned to the innerHTML. Any thoughts on how I would go about doing this?

EDIT

To further explain what i mean:

The user is able to update their webpage by changing images and text. The javascript code behind it will allow enable this. Similar to how a blog works. i want them to be able to preview the changes they make before they are able to commit these changes.

Comment: Please include the code

Comment: learn angular js..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save input data as javascript local storage.
or save input value as an json array and when preview button clicks-> load the array values to your preview div. and in final submit pass that json array to code.

Comment: glad to help you. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you could give us code examples, we can help you further, but from what you provided I can suggest that you make a `div` which will contain the html the user inputs, and after you detect an input you can update the `div.innerHTML` accordingly. Be sure to safety check the html for script tags however, because executing html directly from the user could result in the user putting some nasty javascript in and breaking your site. 
 Happy to help further if you decide to provide some code.

Comment: i dont think you understand what i mean. i will update my post